# Update forked Github repo with all branches

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

I forked a repository on my Github account that has over 1000 commits and 20 branches.

I then cloned it on my local machine.

Is there any way I can update both my local machine's repo and my Github's repo with the original one with all the branches and commits?

Answer (score 4):

maybe it's too late, but a late answer better than nothing:

```
# add the upstream:

git remote add upstream https://github.com/whoever/whatever.git

#create a script to loop through the whole branches and merge changes or create them if not found

sync_all_branch () {
  git fetch upstream
  for upstream_branch in   $( git branch -a |awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} $2=="upstream" {print $3}' ) ;
  do
      if git checkout $upstream_branch
      then
          echo merge $upstream_branch
          git merge -s recursive -Xours upstream/$upstream_branch 
      else
          echo create $upstream_branch
          git checkout -b $upstream_branch upstream/$upstream_branch
      fi
  done
  git checkout master
}

# then call the script

sync_all_branch

#push changes to your remote repository

git push --all
```

if you want to rebase your branches on top of the upstream branches (delete the changes you made and not merged to the upstream), you should change

```
git merge -s recursive -Xours upstream/$upstream_branch
```

with

```
git rebase -s recursive -Xours upstream/$upstream_branch
```

and add "-f" to he last command

*the sync_all_branch script is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766487/2481592